# rdlc report is not working on server

Tags: asp.net, iis, rdlc

The RDCL report created via Visual Studio 2008 is working fine on the local server. But when the same application is hosted on the IIS, HTTP 404-File Not Found error is displayed.

[image]

Does anybody have an idea about this? Please help me.

Comment: Can you show the whole screenshot? It would help if we saw the error itself under Detailed Error Information.

Answer (score 1):

404 is definitely NOT a permission issue.  The virtual / relative / absolute path NEEDS to be verified, looked at and changed.

Try Fiddler or an HTTP Analyzer to see what the exact URL is and be sure it matches up.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the RDCL report file exists on the published directory and/or IIS.